# Redux-Persist: TypeError: Cannot read property 'getItem' of undefined

Tags: node.js, reactjs, redux-saga, redux-persist, connected-react-router

I am working on a react app and recently upgraded to node12.10.0 on my mac and have seen a plethora of package issues.  I upgraded a lot of the packages in my project but am down to an error that seems to occur when I call persistor.purge():

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'getItem' of undefined
getStoredState
node_modules/redux-persist/es/getStoredState.js:19
  16 |   deserialize = defaultDeserialize;
  17 | }
  18 | 
> 19 | return storage.getItem(storageKey).then(function (serialized) {
  20 |   if (!serialized) return undefined;else {
  21 |     try {
  22 |       var state = {};
View compiled
Object../src/index.js
src/index.js:26
  23 | debugger;
  24 | debugger;
  25 | 
> 26 | getStoredState({}).then((err, restoredState) => {
  27 |     if(restoredState) {
  28 |         let storedAppVersion = restoredState.app ? restoredState.app.version : null;
  29 |         // Purge the persisted state if the version has changed
```

The error itself seems to occur when I hit persistor.purge() in the following reducer code:

```
case REHYDRATE:
      let isValid = isTokenInLocalStorageValid();
      if(isValid) {
        let storedState = action.payload.user;
        let newState = Object.assign({}, storedState, { status: null });
        return newState;
      }
    debugger;
    debugger;
      persistor.purge();
```

Here is the code where I am creating the peristor and the store:

```
export const history = createBrowserHistory();

const sagaMiddleware = createSagaMiddleware();
const initialState = {}
const middleware = [
    thunk,
    sagaMiddleware,
    routerMiddleware(history)
]

const composedEnhancers = compose(
    applyMiddleware(...middleware)
)

debugger;
debugger;

const persistConfig = {
    key: 'root',
    storage: localforage,
}

const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, rootReducer(history));
const store = createStore(
    persistedReducer,
    initialState,
    composedEnhancers
)
store.runSaga = sagaMiddleware.run(sagas);
let persistor = persistStore(store)

export default () => {
    return { store, persistor }
}
```

I reviewed the setup examples and am not seeing where the issue could be.

Answer (score 1):

For some reason it's saying storage is undefined. I'm sure you most likely have checked this already, but in the file that the error points to; are you importing storage?

Comment: Yes.  It should be happening here: const persistConfig = {
    key: 'root',
    storage: localforage,
}

Comment: I can't spot the issue either. Are you familiar with react testing library? It's included in react applications and is very useful in debugging; especially when combined with jest; which I believe is also included.

Comment: I will have to review the react testing library.  Not familiar at this time.

Comment: It's amazing and really uncovers issues when you can't figure out what went wrong